# Add keyframe to middle of video without reencoding entire video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I need to add I-frames to the middle of mp4s at ad breaks so I can segment to HLS and have I-frames when the video cues back in. I know how to do this while reencoding the entire video and forcing key frames at particular spots, but I'd much rather cut out the spot (maybe 1 second of video) where the keyframe is needed, add the keyframe, then stitch the video back together. This should greatly reduce encoding time since I can mostly copy codecs except for the one second of video where the I-frame is being added.

The only problem is that the video profile and settings change where I'm adding the I-frame and I don't get a clean stitch when putting it all back together. I understand I can do a reencode with the `concat`, but I'm trying to avoid that processing time.

Some simple examples of what I'm trying to do with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 30 -t 1 -c:a copy -y -copyts clipped2.mp4

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -t 30 -c copy -y -copyts clipped1.mp4

ffmpeg -i "concat:clipped1.mp4|clipped2.mp4" -c copy -y newOutput.mp4
```

I might have to use `ffprobe` and specify bitrate, profile, and other settings for the 1 second clip so that it doesn't default to some random stuff, but I still can't get this to work right.

Has anybody accomplished this? This is specifically being done for server side ad insertion.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51995276/2903532)

Answer (score -1):

I am copying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52013433/2903532):

You can use ffmpeg to insert keyframes where you want them using the `-force_key_frames` option.

eg:

```
./ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v copy -force_key_frames 0:05:00,0:10:00 out.mp4
```

will put a keyframe as close to the 5 and 10s mark as it can. The time values can be in hh:mm:ss format, or just seconds (single values, no colons).

You can check if there are frames inserted where you want them using:

```
./ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time out.mp4
```

Comment: The command for inserting keyframes produce a copy of the input file, with no keyframes added (and subtitles stripped – which I expected since you don't try to keep those explicitly). Apparently one cannot add keyframes without reencoding the video (meaning that `-force_key_frames` will have no effect together since you're just copying the video data with `-c:v copy`).